# Error 1045 access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password no)

Tags: php, mysql, database, odbc, mysql-5.0

I'm absolutely new to this area. I am getting the following difficulty:

When I try the mysql command on the shell, Start->cmd->mysql:

```
Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I don't know why, because if i try to access in MySql by QueryBrowser it works fine.

If i try to connect by a PHP script:

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "username_of_Admin", "password_of_Admin");
$db=mysql_select_db("db_name");

if (!$conn)
    {
    printf("Connection Error: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
?>
```

I receive the error:

```
Connection Error:
```

From Windows MySQL installer:
mysql-essential-5.0.27-win32 and
mysql-gui-tools-5.0-r6-win32

Answer (score 2):

for some reason, the ODBC user is the default username under windows even if you didn't create that user at setup time.  simply typing

> mysql

without specifying a username will attempt to connect with the non-existent ODBC username, and give:

> Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

instead, try specifying a username that you know, for example:

> mysql -uroot -p

Answer (score 0):

You should not use
`mysql`**i**`_connect_error()` if you use `mysql_connect()`.

try

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "username_of_Admin", "password_of_Admin");
if(!$conn){
    print mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: It's the same thing, but it show the error by the right way: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: can you show exact code(with changed password) and exact error message,please?

Comment: seems that username and password are empty here

Comment: yeah it seems that username and password are empty here but is wrong beacuse i access MySQLQueryBrowser with username:root and password:comp (and it's the administrator user), so the username and password are not empty. The exact code and exact errore message? I've already write them in the last post.

Comment: I tried your PHP code and the error is: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO). Exactly as i write before in my first responde to you.

Comment: I don't know how, but the solution is that:
1)Open MySQLAdministrator, than Click on the "Startup Variables" item on the left, then the "Security" tab. Check the checkbox for "Disable grant tables." 

2) Click the "Service Control" item on the left and then the "Start/Stop Service" tab. 

3) Click "Stop Service" -- once the services has stopped, click the button again to start the service.

Comment: I'm the administrator of Operating System however i have to disable grant tables (as a bypassing administrator privilegies...very very strange). And yes...I'm really confused about that °_°

Comment: BE CAREFUL, i don't know why, but after that solution, my Database MySQL has been "deleted". I have all of databases and tables, but if i open them, i received this error: Error No. 1033 Incorrect information in file: 'filename'. Everything is deleted!! °_° HELP!

Answer (score 0):

From my sense I think you are giving wrong userid or password.
check it carefully that your user id and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

When opening **MySQL Command-Line Client** with **the command** below:

```
mysql
```

So instead, I used **the command** below, then I could open **MySQL Command-Line Client**:

```
mysql -u root -p
```